# Save workbooks with numbers from 1 to 100

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to save my files and add a count after each file, so file 1, next file will have 2 at the end of it and 3 then 4, and so on

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Martin\1BankFiles\Recon" & " " & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".XLSX", FileFormat:=51
```

what to add to the above VBA code to achieve so.

Comment: There is no function to do this automatically, and not enough information to give a meaningful answer. You need a variable to store the current number and you need to add that number to the file name and then increment the number.

Comment: Do you want to save 100 files all at once or do you have a new file every once in a while?

Comment: @FunThomas i have a new file everyday, sometime more than 1 file a day

Comment: Do you want saving **the same workbook** with 100 names, each of them containing an incremented number from 1 to 100? If not, please clarify the above mentioned issue.

Comment: I don't ask how many per day, just if you store them all at once (which means you can use a simple loop), of if you create a file now, stop the code and than later that day create the next and so on.

Comment: @FunThomas oh i see, i create a file now, stop the code and then later that day create the next and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a way to figure out which was the last file written (and if it was written today or earlier).

As your macro stops, using a global variable is not reliable. I guess the easiest way would be to look into the folder where you write the files.

The following function will do exactly that: look for all files with the current date in the file name, figure out the highest number and return the next "free" filename.

```
Function GetNextFilename()
    Const BasePath = "C:\Martin\1BankFiles\"        
    Dim BaseFilename As String
    BaseFilename = "Recon " & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY") & "_"

    Dim filename As String, filenumber As Long, largestNumber As Long
    filename = Dir(BasePath & BaseFilename & "*.xlsx")
    Do While filename <> ""
        filenumber = Val(Mid(filename, Len(BaseFilename) + 1))
        If filenumber > largestNumber Then largestNumber = filenumber
        filename = Dir
    Loop
    GetNextFilename= BasePath & BaseFilename & (largestNumber + 1) & ".xlsx"
End Function
```

Your Save-commmand would simply be

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs GetNextFilename, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
```

Comment: sorry but i forgot to mention that the file type is CSV and i want it to be saved as .XLSX, aslo may i ask why the above code changes the sheet name as i want the sheet name to stay the same.

Comment: My bad, forgot to add the `FileFormat`-part - corrected.